# Adding quotes using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

In the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml change log there is an entry:
0.11.12 (2016-07-06):

```
- added support for roundtrip of single/double quoted scalars using:
  ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(stream, preserve_quotes=True)
```

Using ruamel I can convert:

```
skip: Skip
show: 'Show'
remove: "Remove"
"info_on": "ON"
```

to:

```
skip: Skip
show: Show
remove: Remove
info_on: ON
```

Is there an option in ruamel to *add* rather than *preserve* quotes resulting in:

```
"skip": "Skip"
"show": "Show"
"remove": "Remove"
"info_on": "ON"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the `dump()` option `default_style='"'`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
skip: Skip
show: 'Show'
remove: "Remove"
"info_on": "ON"
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_style='"')
```

in the same way as you can do for the old PyYAML from which ruamel.yaml is derived.

Comment: Also note that you should **not** use `preserve_quotes=True` on loading, as that set individual quoting styles, which cannot be change by the global `default_style` parameter to `round_trip_dump()`